# Patch error: "Unreversed patch detected! Skipping patch."

Tags: patch, berkelium

```
patching file chrome/browser/gpu_process_host_ui_shim.cc
Unreversed patch detected!  Skipping patch.
6 out of 6 hunks ignored -- saving rejects to file chrome/browser/gpu_process_host_ui_shim.cc.rej
```

I get messages similar to this one when running a build script from an open source project (https://github.com/sirikata/berkelium) which:

1. starts by cloning another git repository (chromium)
2. tries to apply patches to this cloned repository

What does this "Unreversed patch detected" message mean?

Answer (score 7):

After checking the contents of the files causing this message to appear, I think I found the "problem".

This apparently corresponds to patches already applied and committed to the repository which have thus no reason to be reapplied.